# I want to replace the timestamp in an html file using sed

Tags: shell, sed, timestamp

I want to replace the timestamp in an html file using sed, the line I want to replace is:

```
"dateModified": "2019-04-03 00:35",
```

I want to update timestamp with current date and time when running the shell script:

```
"dateModified": "timestamp updated",
```

I have tried several things but I do not succeed, the closest I have been is:

```
sed 's/.*"dateModified":.*/"dateModified": "'$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')'",/' /path to file/
```

but there is an error.

I am working on Ubuntu 18.

any suggestion will be very grateful.

Comment: "but there is an error" Do you think you might share that error with the rest of us?

Comment: @miken32 An apology, the error was `sed: -e expression # 1, char 49: unterminated` s' command`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data in 'dat', by gnu sed;
note `` !

```
d="`date`";sed -E "s/(.*\"dateModified\":).*/\1\"$d\",/i" dat
```

to really edit it, add `-i` :  `sed -Ei` ....

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfect, now I will only analyze your answer in detail to understand it.